# Any gotchas/common mistakes for first time players playing Asia Engulfed?

Tags: asia-engulfed

A number of years ago (... 5ish now I think) I played a game called Europe Engulfed a few times, and loved it.  Since moving a few years back, I have not had anyone to play with locally.  Recently, a friend of mine expressed interest, and we are going to try another game in the series first, Asia Engulfed.  I have read that the rules are a little simpler (in that there are many less sub factions), and since I have not played it, I felt it might help even the playing field.

All that said, I remember the first time I played Europe Engulfed, we made a number of strange rules mistakes - the type of thing beginners do when trying out a new, fairly complex board game.  Does anyone have any experience with this game?  Any specific gotchas to watch out for?  Any recommendations for general strategy that I can share with my "opponent"?  As I want to be able to keep playing it, it is in my best interest to make sure we start on as even a footing as possible.  :)